# Why SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Follwing code is working but producing always this error message.

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

```
def outliers_resultat_calcule (df):
    max_995 = df.describe(percentiles=[.005, .5, .995]).loc[['max'],'RESULTAT_CALCULE']
    max_995 = int(max_995)
    min_005 = df.describe(percentiles=[.005, .5, .995]).loc[['min'],'RESULTAT_CALCULE']
    min_005 = int(min_005)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['RESULTAT_CALCULE'] > max_995:
            row['RESULTAT_CALCULE'] = max_995
        elif row['RESULTAT_CALCULE'] < min_005:
            row['RESULTAT_CALCULE'] = min_005
    df['Delta_Resultat_Calcule'] = df['RESULTAT_CALCULE'].shift(-1) - df['RESULTAT_CALCULE']
    df['Delta_Resultat_Calcule'] = df['Delta_Resultat_Calcule'].shift(1)
    return df

df_179_1 = outliers_resultat_calcule(df_179_1)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) may answer your question

Comment: Thx but where exactly in my example above i have to use .loc ?